# How can i hide/disable done button on soft keyboard android?

Tags: android, textwatcher, android-keypad

I am working with Amazon S3 api.

Problem: Working with TextWatcher. As soon as user enters more than 3 characters in the edittext, api is called and it shows matched results. The problem starts as soon the user hit the done/enter button on soft keyboard, the api is called again and it searches again. Can i stop this second call somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the enter button or is it ok to remove it?

Comment: i suggest you to do a hack on ime option programmatically

Answer (score 4):

you can change it from xml:

```
<EditText
...
android:imeOptions="actionNone"/>
```

or from code:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);
```

It will remove the done button whenever user trigger the softkeybord

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to override the onKeyListener method in your control, to let it detect if the key pressed is 'enter' and add the code you want your 'enter' key to do ?

`edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {`

Answer (score 0):

just handle done click and hide the soft keyboard

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
           // hide your keyboard here
           try {
                   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   if (inputMethodManager != null && activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
             inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                   }
           } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

to you xml and enter button should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);`

but it won't hide the Enter/Next